# Swift 2 Programmatically Constraints, i can't see the web view

Tags: swift, constraints, swift2, wkwebview

i have a webkit and under the webkit there is another view... so i have three view = view, secondView(the one contain the WKWebView) and bannerView(with ADS). I added WKWebView to the secondView programmatically but bannerView and their constraints are set in storyboard. Now i need to set the constraints for WKWebView, i saw hundreds of tutorial, run without crash and problems but i can't see the WKWebView! how can i fix that ?

Code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var bannerView: GADBannerView!



    @IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!
       var webView = WKWebView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())






        //bannerView.adUnitID = ""
        //bannerView.rootViewController = self
        //var request = GADRequest()
        //request.testDevices = ["kGADSimulatorID"]
        //bannerView.loadRequest(request)



        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preferences

        webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 543)


            webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12"




        let url = NSURL(string:"https://apple.com/")
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView.loadRequest(req)

        secondView.addSubview(webView)
        secondView.bringSubviewToFront(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: secondView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: secondView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: secondView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        secondView.addConstraints([xConstraint, yConstraint, bottomConstraint])

       /*
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)

       let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)

      let bottomConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        */


     /*   var LeftwebViewConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20)

        var RightwebViewConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20)

        var BottomwebViewConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)


       // view.addConstraints([LeftwebViewConstraints, RightwebViewConstraints, BottomwebViewConstraints])
         NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([LeftwebViewConstraints, RightwebViewConstraints, BottomwebViewConstraints])


        */


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




}
```

Comment: You are either using Swift 1 **or** 2 (your code looks like 2). Could you please edit your question to reflect which version you are using, and please try to indent your code properly.

Comment: it's swift 2.0 but it's good also 1.0 as i can convert it

Comment: anyway i edit the title... do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: By the way, you go throu the trouble of instantiating the `preferences` and `configuration`, but you never use them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would appear that you are missing some constraints.

I might suggest adding all of the necessary constraints using VFL, which may be more intuitive:

```
secondView.addSubview(webView)
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let views = ["webView" : webView]
secondView.addSubview(webView)
secondView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
secondView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

This obviously assumes that the constraints for `secondView` were defined correctly in the first place. Check its `frame` before you start losing any sleep over the `frame` of the `webView`.

But note, I don't manually set the `frame` of the `webView`, but rather I simply defined both horizontal and vertical constraints.